# PHP form submiting

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a form with four values, `player1`, `player2`, `awayTeam`, and `homeTeam`.

After checking if values are not empty it does not want to send results to database. I am not sure why it does not want to submit.

There are as well two random numbers which will be compared and based on `if num1 > num2` record should be submitted.

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","test", "passowrd", "test" );

if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    die ("DB has not been connected");
}

// create two random numbers
$Num1 = rand();
$Num2 = rand();

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $playerOne = mysqli_real_escape_string ($link, $_POST['playerOne']);
    $playerTwo = mysqli_real_escape_string ($link, $_POST['playerTwo']);
    $awayTeam = mysqli_real_escape_string ($link, $_POST['awayTeam']);
    $homeTeam = mysqli_real_escape_string ($link, $_POST['homeTeam']);  

    //check if player one is empty
    if (empty($playerOne)) {
        echo "Game Creator PSN required!" . "<br>";
    }

    //check if player two is empty
    if (empty($playerTwo)) {
        echo "Second Player PSN required!";
    }
} else {
    //compare two numbers
    if ($Num1 > $Num2) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO randomizer (playerOne, playerTwo, awayteam, homeTeam) VALUES (' $playerOne', '$playerTwo', '$awayTeam', '$homeTeam')";
        if ($link->query($sql) === true) {
            echo "Record Added Sucessfully";
        } else {
            echo "There was a problem";
        }
    } else {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO randomizer (playerOne, playerTwo, awayteam, homeTeam) VALUES (' $playerTwo', '$playerOne', '$awayTeam', '$homeTeam')";
        if ($link->query($sql) === true) {
            echo "Record Added Sucessfully";
        } else {
            echo "There was a problem";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Why 2 `insert` statements? What happens with the current execution?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk. Using bound parameters is less verbose and easier to review to check you’re doing it properly.

Comment: Do try and get out of the habit of cluttering up your code with needless things like `=== TRUE`. Many functions are designed to return values that evaluate as logically true or false so that's redundant. It's also a bad idea to create throw-away variables like `$sql` and then immediately supply them to a function. Instead supply that string to the function directly.

Comment: You're also mixing and matching the object-oriented style with the really old-school procedural one. I'd strongly recommend sticking with the object-oriented style exclusively as it's less verbose and you won't make the mistake of accidentally using the `mysql_query` family of functions which are entirely unrelated but often differ by just the letter `i`.

Answer (score 0):

1. if post data is null, you did nothing. I've never see exit or other exit words, in the SQL words you'll get errs
2. what different with $num1 > $num2 in your code? they executed the same codes